# In Expression Engine, I can't "open" entries, they only offer "closed" as an option

Tags: channel-entries, members, ee1, groups

I have taken over an old Expression Engine 1.7 site and am trying to create a Member group that offers limited admin privs rather than create a "Superadmin."

The problem is that I want the user to be able to create, edit, publish, unpublish section entries, but when they do, the sections exist only as "closed" (unpublished) and when I try to edit them, "closed" is the only option in the pulldown.  I am assuming there's a setting in the Group preferences that is preventing this, but I don't know what setting.  I've tried a number of them and nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions would be great.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these things:

- the weblog has some statuses group assigned to it
- the members group is authorized to publish entries in this weblog
- the members group is authorized to edit entries authored by others

Comment: Can you explain just a little more about the first one, the "the weblog has some statuses group assigned to it"?  

I am still getting the same result even when I've cloned the "SuperAdmin" into a new group (I'm calling it "Fulladmin").  It only offers "closed" as a publishing option.

Comment: Check "Status Group" under Admin  ›  Weblog Administration  ›  Weblog Management  ›  Edit Group Preferences

Comment: Thank you, yes, that fixed it!  It had "None" as the status group, and the only other option was "default."  When I switched it, everything worked!  Yay!